# Call for SFX ideas for 'The Guide To Sound Effects'

Tags: effect, guide

Hey guys and gals

We recently gave [The Guide To Sound Effects](http://www.epicsound.com/sfx) a major overhaul, with a new look, search and more -  and now we're looking to add more sfx ideas to the list.

So if you've got any ideas to share on ways of making specific sfx, please submit them using the form on the site and we'll add them.

The Guide is at http://www.epicsound.com/sfx - hope you find it useful and we look forward to your ideas!

Cheers,

-Asbjoern and David